# How to use a button that is being generated by a function?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm creating a facebook clone to learn about web developing. So I've made the user profile and now I want the user to be able to change his profile picture. I wrote a function that whenever the user hovers over the profile picture an edit button appears. 
 I want to use that edit button to make a form appear where he can upload a new photo. How can I do this?
 This is the code of the function:

```
function editProfilePic(output){
    var x = document.createElement("Button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Edit");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById(output).appendChild(x);
}
```

Also is there a way to make the button appear once when the user has the mouse over the picture and then disappear when he takes it off the picture? Right now whenever the user enters the picture I generate a new button...

Comment: I think what you need is [onmouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover) event.

Comment: `x.addEventListener('click', function() { // do something when clicked; });`

Comment: Yes, I've got the onmouseover event but the button that is being generated stays after the cursor leaves the picture. If I put the cursor in the image again I will have two buttons etc.

Comment: cache the button, e.g. in a button variable that is outside of the function scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better assign an id to the Edit button that you are creating on mouse over

```
function editProfilePic(output){
   var x = document.createElement("Button");
   var t = document.createTextNode("Edit");
   x.id = "btnEdit";
   x.appendChild(t);
   document.getElementById(output).appendChild(x);
}
```

So that when you hide it, you can easily grab the edit button using its id

```
function hideButton(output){ 
   document.getElementById("btnEdit").remove(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `onmouseover` event to create the button, then add a `onmouseout` event to destroy the button once the mouse exit the area.

Comment: Did this with this code `function hideButton(output){
 //document.getElementById(output).style.visibility = "hidden";
 document.getElementById(output).remove();
 }` with both options the button disappears when I get out of the picture but when I enter the picture it doesn't create a new button.

Comment: Try create the button (as an object) outside of the function. Then inside your `editProfilePic` function append that button. With this you can use the button anywhere flexibly.